# Soft Keyboard overlaping control (WPF, desktop)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, desktop-application

first I would like to stress that I am looking for a **Windows DESKTOP WPF** solution, so please no android. Thank you.

Second, I am fairly new to WPF and designing software for Windows Tablet, so please bear with me... And please do be explicit in your answers.

Third, the target software will run on a Windows Tablet (Win 8.0/8.1) and is being developed with Visual Studio 2013 Pro (C#, Desktop App, WPF).

**OK, here is my problem:**

I have been using a Textbox inherited class to show the Soft Keyboard when the user touches the Textbox (class code bellow). This part actually works well.
My problem is that the Soft Keyboard may popup over my actual control. In WinRT this would not happen since the OS seems to scroll the said control up until it becomes visible, but with DESKTOP app no such feature exists.

So my question is: does anyone know how to solve this overlap issue?

How could I (in Win desktop app) replicate the normal WinRT behavior?

Should I be using some other API to call the Soft Keyboard?

***Code for the "TouchTextbox" class:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WPF_DT_Soft_Keyboard
{
    class TouchTextbox : TextBox 
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;        

        protected override void OnGotFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
            ShowSoftKeyboard();
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            HideSoftKeyboard();
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewKeyUp(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyUp(e);
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter) HideSoftKeyboard();
        }

        private void ShowSoftKeyboard()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
        }

        private void HideSoftKeyboard()
        {
            int iHandle = FindWindow("IPTIP_Main_Window", "");
            if (iHandle > 0)
            {
                SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use setwindowpos after you start it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried your approach... first I was getting a ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED from the GetLastError after calling SetWindowPos. So then I ran my VS13 as administrator, the error went away but still the soft keyboard window is NOT moved... Any idea?

Comment: How are you calling it? like this? SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

Comment: SetWindowPos(iHandle, HWND_TOP, 500, 500, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);

Comment: I just tried your exact call "SetWindowPos(handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);" And I get no error (function returns 1) but the Soft Keyboard position is still unchanged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally found a decent solution.
I have encapsulated it into the TouchTextbox class bellow.
For it to work properly, the TouchTextbox must be contained withing a [ScrollViewer] control.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    namespace WPF_DT_Soft_Keyboard
    {
        class TouchTextbox : TextBox 
        {

        /// <summary>
        /// Private Container
        /// </summary>
        DispatcherTimer mBringIntoViewTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        /// <summary>
        ///  DLL imports
        /// </summary>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int MoveWindow(int hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetWindowPos(int hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetLastError();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constante
        /// </summary>
        public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        public const int HWND_TOP = 0;
        public const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        public const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
        public const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        public const int BRING_INTO_VIEW_DELAY = 500;


        /// <summary>
        /// TouchTextbox
        /// </summary>
        public TouchTextbox()
        {
            mBringIntoViewTimer.IsEnabled = false;
            mBringIntoViewTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick;
            mBringIntoViewTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, BRING_INTO_VIEW_DELAY);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// MyTimer_Tick
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mBringIntoViewTimer.IsEnabled = false;
            this.BringIntoView();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// OnGotFocus
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnGotFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
            ShowSoftKeyboard();
            mBringIntoViewTimer.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        ///// <summary>
        ///// OnLostFocus
        ///// </summary>
        ///// <param name="e"></param>
        //protected override void OnLostFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    base.OnLostFocus(e);
        //    HideSoftKeyboard();
        //}

        /// <summary>
        /// OnPreviewKeyUp
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnPreviewKeyUp(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewKeyUp(e);
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter) HideSoftKeyboard();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ShowSoftKeyboard
        /// </summary>
        private void ShowSoftKeyboard()
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7", true).SetValue("EdgeTargetDockedState", "1", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// HideSoftKeyboard
        /// </summary>
        private void HideSoftKeyboard()
        {
            int iHandle = FindWindow("IPTIP_Main_Window", "");
            if (iHandle > 0)
            {
            SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this does not work for you on your tablet you may need to maximize the keyboard once and then it should be good.